# How do I transfer ownership of a unique_ptr when returning a tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm trying to return a tuple, one of the elements of which is a `std::unique_ptr`.  I want to transfer the ownership of the `unique_ptr` to the caller.  How do I do this?

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    B(int i) : i_(i) {}

    int getI() const { return i_; }
private:
   int i_;
};

tuple<unique_ptr<B>, int>
getThem()
{
    unique_ptr<B> ptr(new B(10));
    return make_tuple(ptr, 50);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    unique_ptr<B> b;
    int got = 0;

    tie(b, got) = getThem();

    cout << "b: " << b->getI() << endl;
    cout << "got: " << got << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile because the copy constructor of `unique_ptr` is deleted, for obvious reasons.  But how to I indicate I want to move the `unique_ptr` into the `tie`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essentially you just need to explicitly move the non-copyable types into the tuple, thus using `std::move`. [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) has the appropriate constructors to copy and move the types internally (the move being appropriate here).

As follows;

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    B(int i) : i_(i) {}

    int getI() const { return i_; }
private:
    int i_;
};

tuple<unique_ptr<B>, int>
getThem()
{
    unique_ptr<B> ptr(new B(10));
    return make_tuple(std::move(ptr), 50); // move the unique_ptr into the tuple
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unique_ptr<B> b;
    int got = 0;

    tie(b, got) = getThem();

    cout << "b: " << b->getI() << endl;
    cout << "got: " << got << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome Niall! I apologize for the unique_ptr<int> mistake.  I didn't notice that in the page full of template errors from the unique_ptr copy. I had found this myself and just updated my question before your response.  Now that I corrected that, please remove that from your answer and I'll accept it.  (Not because I'm trying to cover up my mistake, but because having that in your answer may confuse future readers of your answer.)

Comment: Actually, I don't want to hold your answer hostage.  I accepted it.  But I do suggest you update it for future readers.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @firebush. Thanks, I stepped away for a bit. I've updated the answer given your updates.

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::move` to invoke the move operator instead.

```
return make_tuple(std::move(ptr), 50);
```